# how to install Openmpi for xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, mpi

I'm trying to run some MPI programs in xcode 4. I installed openmpi from MacPort by typing `sudo port install openmpi` and the installation finished normally. Then I added opt/local/include/openmpi to my user header search paths, dragged the "libmpi.dylib" and "libmpi_cxx.dylib" into my project.

But then when I tried to run the program, I got the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MPI_Comm_accept", referenced from:
      MPI::Intracomm::Accept(char const*, MPI::Info const&, int) const in main.o
  "_MPI_Comm_connect", referenced from:
      MPI::Intracomm::Connect(char const*, MPI::Info const&, int) const in main.o
  "_MPI_Comm_disconnect", referenced from:
      MPI::Comm::Disconnect() in main.o
  "_MPI_Comm_get_errhandler", referenced from:
      MPI::Comm::Get_errhandler() const in main.o
  "_MPI_Comm_set_errhandler", referenced from:
      MPI::Comm::Set_errhandler(MPI::Errhandler const&) const in main.o
  "_MPI_Comm_spawn", referenced from:
      MPI::Intracomm::Spawn(char const*, char const**, int, MPI::Info const&, int) const in main.o
      MPI::Intracomm::Spawn(char const*, char const**, int, MPI::Info const&, int, int*) const in main.o
  "_MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple", referenced from:
      MPI::Intracomm::Spawn_multiple(int, char const**, char const***, int const*, MPI::Info const*, int) in main.o
      MPI::Intracomm::Spawn_multiple(int, char const**, char const***, int const*, MPI::Info const*, int, int*) in main.o
  "_MPI_Grequest_complete", referenced from:
      MPI::Grequest::Complete() in main.o
  "_MPI_Op_commutative", referenced from:
      MPI::Op::Is_commutative() const in main.o
  "_MPI_Reduce_local", referenced from:
      MPI::Op::Reduce_local(void const*, void*, int, MPI::Datatype const&) const in main.o
  "_MPI_Win_call_errhandler", referenced from:
      MPI::Win::Call_errhandler(int) const in main.o
  "_MPI_Win_get_errhandler", referenced from:
      MPI::Win::Get_errhandler() const in main.o
  "_MPI_Win_set_errhandler", referenced from:
      MPI::Win::Set_errhandler(MPI::Errhandler const&) const in main.o
  "_ompi_mpi_comm_null", referenced from:
      MPI::Intracomm::Intracomm(ompi_communicator_t*) in main.o
      MPI::Graphcomm::Graphcomm(ompi_communicator_t* const&) in main.o
      MPI::Cartcomm::Cartcomm(ompi_communicator_t* const&) in main.o
  "_ompi_mpi_comm_world", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_ompi_mpi_double", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_ompi_mpi_op_sum", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_ompi_op_set_cxx_callback", referenced from:
      MPI::Op::Init(void (*)(void const*, void*, int, MPI::Datatype const&), bool) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I missing anything in the above installation processes?

Comment: Check that Open MPI was compiled as 64-bit (x86_64) or as fat 64- and 32-bit and not as 32-bit (i386) only (e.g. run `file /path/to/libmpi.dylib` in Terminal.app). If it is 32-bit only, either recompile it or switch your project's target to i386.

Comment: macports is always a good option if your having trouble with Xcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, when I compiled openmpi from the sources, added header and library search paths, but forgot to add libraries as the linker flags to the build settings. Adding them solved this. You can type `mpicc –showme` to see the libraries that are necessary for mpi to run.

Comment: For me it returns the following: `gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi -lm`

Answer (score 19):

First be sure to have installed MPI.
I personally use [brew](http://brew.sh/) to do so.

```
brew update
brew install open-mpi
```

Then check the requirements for c++:

```
mpic++ -showme
```

or `mpicc -showme for c`

My output with mpic++ is :

```
clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.6/include -L/usr/local/opt/libevent/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.6/lib -lmpi_cxx -lmpi
```

Then we got the include path, library path and some other flags. From the output of the previous command we got that we need to add:

1. "/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.6/include" in the **“Search Paths – Header Search Paths”**
2. "/usr/local/opt/libevent/lib" and "/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.6/lib" in  the *“Search Paths – Library Search Paths”*
3. "-lmpi_cxx -lmpi" in the **“Linking – Other Linker Flags”**

These can be done through the **Build Settings** option from the Xcode project.

Because *mpi* need to use it's own program to *run* ours we need to change the *Executable*.

1. Select **"Edit schemes"** [image]
2. In the dialog box under **Info** for the **Executable** choose **Other...** from the combobox.[image]
3. Change it to **mpiexec** wich is an alias of "orterun". For me it's in */usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.8.6/bin*. Note that this is usually an hidden folder. You can open it by pressing `cmd + shift + g`.
4. For running **mpiexec** need to know as arguments **the number of processors** and the **executable file**. So, in the same dialog box under **Arguments**

   - add **"-n X"** where X is the number of processors you want to use *"for this example i will use 2"*.
   - add **"$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$EXECUTABLE_PATH"** wich is the combination of environment variables that specify the executable file.

[image]

- Then add `<mpi.h>` header to your source code.
- Run it and you will see 2 *"Hello, World!"* (because I use *-n 2* for the example).

sources : [open-mpi xcode FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx), [Debugging & running MPI programs in Xcode](http://wp.yaonan.li/archives/1065)

Comment: Great tutorial! Should be top answer

Comment: The linker flag "-lmpi_cxx" failed for me on Mac OS 10.13, had to use "-lm" instead. Also note the hint on overlong temp file paths in https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx on this OS.

Comment: yeah this answer is quite old, I invite you to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Or just type mpic++ instead of mpicc. That worked for me ;)